# Swift: Thread safe Singleton, why do we use sync for read?

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch

While making a thread-safe Singleton, it is advised to use a sync for read and an async with a barrier for write operation.

My question is why do we use a sync for read? What might happen if we perform a read with async operation?

Here is an example of what is recommended:

```
func getUser(id: String) throws -> User {
  var user: User!
  try concurrentQueue.sync {
    user = try storage.getUser(id)
  }
  return user
}
func setUser(_ user: User, completion: (Result<()>) -> Void) {
  try concurrentQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
    do {
      try storage.setUser(user)
      completion(.value(())
    } catch {
      completion(.error(error))
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Would you want the `return user` statement to execute before the `user = try storage.getUser(id)` statement? If not, then you need to use `sync` to enforce the ordering you do want. That's what `sync` is for, to make sure the code in the block has completed executing before the caller proceeds to its next statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all in what you want. By changing get user to async, then you need to use a callback to wait for the value.

```
func getUser(id: String, completion: @escaping (Result<User>) -> Void) -> Void {
    concurrentQueue.async {
        do {
            let user = try storage.getUser(id)
            completion(.value(user))
        } catch {
            completion(.error(error))
        }
    }
}

func setUser(_ user: User, completion: @escaping (Result<()>) -> Void) {
    concurrentQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
        do {
            try storage.setUser(user)
            completion(.value(()))
        } catch {
            completion(.error(error))
        }
    }
}
```

That changes the API of get user, so now when calling get user, a callback will need to be used.

Instead of somethings like this

```
do {
    let user = try manager.getUser(id: "test")
    updateUI(user: user)
} catch {
    handleError(error)
}
```

you will need something like this

```
manager.getUser(id: "test") { [weak self] result in
    switch result {
    case .value(let user):  self?.updateUI(user: user)
    case .error(let error): self?.handleError(error)
    }
}
```

Assuming you have somethings like a view controller with a property named `manager` and methods `updateUI()` and `handleError()`

Answer (score 2):

The concept of using concurrent queue with “read concurrently with `sync`; write with barrier with `async`” is a very common synchronization pattern called “reader-writer”. The idea is that the concurrent queue is just for synchronizing writes with a barrier, but that reads will take place concurrently with respect to other reads.

So, here’s a simple, real-world example of using reader-writer for synchronized access to some private state property:

```
enum State {
    case notStarted
    case running
    case complete
}

class ComplexProcessor {
    private var readerWriterQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "...", attributes: .concurrent)

    // private backing stored property
    private var _state: State = .notStarted

    // exposed computed property synchronizes access using reader-writer pattern
    var state: State {
        get { readerWriterQueue.sync { _state } }
        set { readerWriterQueue.async { self._state = newValue } }
    }

    func start() {
        state = .running
        DispatchQueue.global().async {
            // do something complicated here

            self.state = .complete
        }
    }
}
```

Consider:

```
let processor = ComplexProcessor()
processor.start()
```

And then, later:

```
if processor.state == .complete {
    ...
}
```

The `state` computed property is using the reader-writer pattern to offer thread-safe access to the underlying stored property. It synchronizes access to some memory location, and we are confident that it will be responsive. In this case, we don’t need confusing `@escaping` closures: The `sync` reads result in very simple code that is easy to reason about.

---

That having been said, in your example, you’re not just synchronizing interaction with some property, but synchronizing the interaction with `storage`. If that’s local storage that is guaranteed to be responsive, then the reader-writer pattern is probably fine.

But if `storage` methods could take anything more than a few milliseconds to run, you wouldn’t want to use the reader-writer pattern. The fact that `getUser` can throw errors makes me wonder if `storage` is already doing complicated processing. And even if it is just reading quickly from some local store, what if it was later refactored to interact with some remote store, subject to unknown network latency/issues? Bottom line, it is questionable to have the `getUser` method making assumptions about implementation details of `storage`, assuming that the value will always be returned quickly.

In that case, you would refactor `getUser` method to use `@escaping` completion handler closure, as [suggested by Jeffery Thomas](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59017479/1271826). We never want to have a synchronous method that might take more than a few milliseconds, because we never want to block the calling thread (especially if it’s the main thread).

---

By the way, if you stay with reader-writer pattern, you can simplify your `getUser`, because `sync` returns whatever value its closure returns:

```
func getUser(id: String) throws -> User {
    return try concurrentQueue.sync {
        try storage.getUser(id)
    }
}
```

And you can’t use `try` in conjunction with `async` (only within your `do`-`catch` block). So it’s just:

```
func setUser(_ user: User, completion: (Result<()>) -> Void) {
    concurrentQueue.async(flags: .barrier) {
        do {
            try storage.setUser(user)
            completion(.value(())
        } catch {
            completion(.error(error))
        }
    }
}
```